# Как получить координаты курсора на форме?

Tags: c#, winforms

Мне надо получить координаты курсора НА ФОРМЕ, как это сделать? Пробывал MousePosition, Cursor.Position и другое, но они все возращают координаты курсора не на форме, а на экране.

Comment: [PointToClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient?view=windowsdesktop-6.0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Зная позицию формы (и размер) на экране можно подсчитать позицию курсора в ее координатах.
2. Можно использовать события MouseMove и т.д., где координаты передаются обработчику события в MouseEventArgs.